# How can I solve heap-buffer-overflow in my C-code?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, libfuzzer

I am fairly new to C-coding and I have a task where we run libFuzzer on a basic C-program to exploit problems and fix them. This is my C-program (it takes a string input and changes "&" to "&amp", ">" to "&gt" and "<" to "&lt"):

```
char *checkString(char str[50]) {
  int i;
  char *newstr;
  newstr = (char *)malloc(200);
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    if (str[i] == '&') {
      const char *ch = "&amp";
      strncat(newstr, ch, 4);
    } else if (str[i] == '<') {
      const char *ch = "&lt";
      strncat(newstr, ch, 3);
    } else if (str[i] == '>') {
      const char *ch = "&gt";
      strncat(newstr, ch, 3);
    } else {
      const char ch = str[i];
      strncat(newstr, &ch, 1);
    }
  }
  return newstr;
}
```

This is the error message from libFuzzer:

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/path/to/a.out+0x50dc14) in strncat
```

Anybody who knows how to possibly fix this heap buffer overflow problem? Thanks!

Comment: It would help to set `newstr` to an empty string before starting your `strncat`'s, and to null-terminate it at the end.

Comment: A nitpick and probably not your problem, but there's no guarantee that `newstr` is big enough, since (despite its declaration) `checkString` actually receives a pointer to a potentially arbitrarily-long string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `newstr = (char *)malloc(200);`, `newstr` is not yet properly initialized so you must not call `strncat( newstr, ... )`.
You can solve that e.g. by calling `strcpy( newstr, "" );` after `malloc()` or by replacing `malloc(200)` with `calloc(200,1)` which fills the entire buffer with NUL.

Besides, as @stevesummit has mentioned, despite its declaration there is no guarantee, that `strlen(str) < 50`. So instead of allocating a fix number of 200 characters, you should alloc `strlen(str)*4 + 1`
... or `strlen(str)*5 + 1` if what you're doing is HTML esacping and you realize that `&` should be replaced by `&amp;`